# PHP to html with twitter api 1.1

Tags: php, html, twitter

This is a simple question but i have the following php file that references some code to get a twitter follower count.  This all works but in my html website file i want to display the "follower count" as text and in my php I am not sure what line to add.  I already have the script referenced in my html and right now i am trying to get it by using `<span id="followers_count"></span>` but nothing appears.  Am i doing that wrong or what do i add to my php file to take follower count and display it as text in my html?  Thanks!

```
<?php   
    require_once('js/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

    /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "key here",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "key here",
    'consumer_key' => "key here",
    'consumer_secret' => "key here"
    );

    $ta_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
    $getfield = '?screen_name=inovize;
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $follow_count=$twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($ta_url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
    $data = json_decode($follow_count, true);
    $followers_count=$data[0]['user']['followers_count'];
    echo $followers_count;

    *Do I add anything here to take followers_count to html text?*


    });
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that the `user_timeline` Twitter API call has a rate limit of 180 calls per rate limit window (15 minutes). Since your follower count is probably not changing on a minute-to-minute basis, you should cache the result somewhere and only update it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently echoing out the count where ever this code resides in your PHP code, which is most likely at the top of your page.

```
echo $followers_count;
```

comment out this line

```
//echo $followers_count;
```

and where you have your span echo that line

```
<span id="followers_count"><?php echo $followers_count; ?></span>
```

Comment: do i need to use the span id?